# Python - opencv Draw Bounding Boxes around Canny edge image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, bounding-box

I have a image that processed to find edges with canny edges algorithm, now i need to draw bounding boxes around this shapes. The problem is that when i use

```
cv2.findContours
```

i get this error

```
error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp:197: error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats) [Start]FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode != CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only in function 'cvStartFindContours_Impl'
```

the image is the shape of a pig.
[image]

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: Convert your image to uint8. It is likely floats and that won't work with findContours

Answer (score 0):

Need more information about your situation, but it looks like you have to convert your image before using that function.
like

```
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image = image.astype("uint8")
```

try execute this code before using that function.